# calling an child form event replacing or avoiding the mdi parent form event

Tags: c#, winforms, gridcontrol

In `mdimain_MdiChildActivate` the application logic is defined for all child forms
related to `GridControl` `mouseDoubleClick` event . 
It is working fine for all grid containing child forms but in some case where grid `mouseDoubleClick` is defined internal for the Child Form.
So, the event is fired twice one from `MdiParent` and for internal part.
Is there any way such that `MdiParent` Parent Control event does not fire's for this `mouseDoubleClick` case comparing/validating the `ifexist` case for Child Form without changing the code in MDI form.

sample example :

```
private void MDIMain_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code should not work
}      

private void MainGridControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  ///  Child Form : code should work
}
```

Comment: What is `GridControl`? some kind of `DataGridView`?

Comment: yes! An DevExpress XtraGrid Control

Answer (score 0):

This approach detects `WM_NCHITTEST` message sent to your `MainGridControl` before `MdiChildActivate` is fired. This can only detect if your mouse is used (Click, DoubleClick) on the `MainGridControl` but I think it suits in your case.

```
public class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      Load += (s,e) => {
         gridProc.AssignHandle(MainGridControl.Handle);
      };
   }
   MainGridProc gridProc = new MainGridProc();
   private void MDIMain_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(gridProc.HitTestOn) { gridProc.HitTestOn = false; return; }
       //code is still run if HitTestOn = false
       //.......
   }   
   public class MainGridProc : NativeWindow {
      protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
         if(m.Msg == 0x84)//WM_NCHITTEST
         {
            HitTestOn = true;
         }
         base.WndProc(ref m);
      }
      public bool HitTestOn {get;set;}
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code using flag,interface access but it is needed to avoid or replace MdiChildActivation code with the Child one (for some case). Code should be such that independent of Parent Form and does not resembles(auto call) the MdiParent Activate controls.

Comment: for more Clarification : remove child Form access from parent Form MDI

Comment: @user1069940 try my updated answer, if it doesn't work, I don't have any other solution, your problem is not trivial because of the `Control events system design`, the key point is somehow we have to know the `MouseDoubleClick` before `MdiChildActivate`